# How would I move this piece of text more to the left without bringing the navigation with it

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to move a piece of text to the left, the text is inside a span tag.

I've tried using margin & padding but it just pushes the navigation down if the margin is too high or the padding is too high.

```html
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="container">
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
                        <span>First Project</span>
                    </a>
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Features</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Pricing</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Faq</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Examples</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>
</body>
</html>
```

```css
/* Navigation */
nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    float: right;
}

nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
}

nav ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #404040;
    /* Top right bottom left*/
    padding: 0px 35px 0px 0px;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
    color: #888686;
}

/* Branding */
.navbar-brand {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #404040;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
 <div class="container">
            <nav>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
                        <span>First Project</span>
                    </a>
                <ul>

                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Features</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Pricing</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Faq</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Examples</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
```

css:

```
/* Navigation */
nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: space-between;  
}

nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
}

nav ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #404040;
    /* Top right bottom left*/
    padding: 0px 35px 0px 0px;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
    color: #888686;
}

/* Branding Update the value of padding to move right content */
.navbar-brand {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #404040;
    padding-right: 30px;
}
```

screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Still does the same thing, I want it to be a lot to the left but still be aligned with the navigation

Comment: Can you share the screenshot of expected result

Comment: Yes, I want it to be like this: [expected](http://prntscr.com/nt6ndz)
But i'm getting this: [result](http://prntscr.com/nt6nvw)

Comment: One last question sir, I want the navigation and branding to span the entire thing  [link](http://prntscr.com/nt6ylf) how would I do that?

Comment: It is already a link. Just update the href to redirect it to specific page

Comment: uhh what? That's not what I meant, I want it to be like this: [link](http://prntscr.com/nt71nw) where it goes the entire way not like this: [link2](http://prntscr.com/nt71rg) where it is in the center and doesnt cover the entire top part etc.

Comment: Do you want the branding icon to be extreme left and navigation icon to be extreme right?

Comment: No I just want the thing to span the entire thing like take up the entire right and left

Comment: So if you wrap entire nav tag with anchor then it will behave has link. There will be problem in that. So there will be confusion, sometime it will redirect to link provided in anchor tag wrapping the nav and sometime it will redirect to link present on logo and li tag. I am not getting why do you want to do this thing. This is not standard structure.

Comment: you don't understand what i'm asking lol, i'm asking how I can make this like the top thing [screenshot] (http://prntscr.com/nt7bg2) but for my navigation which looks like this currently. [screenshot2] (http://prntscr.com/nt7bnf)

Comment: I m still not getting what are you trying to convey me.  Do you want branding logo to be extreme left and navigation to be extreme right? This is the only thing I can see the difference in screenshot

Comment: dude, look at the screenshot closely, look at how the first screenshot's navigation is like a square that takes up more but the second screenshot only takes up a little bit, i want mine to be like the first screenshot.

Comment: Ohh got it you want  the nav link to be wrap with background which must have 100%width..

Comment: Use below css .container{ background: red}

Comment: How do i make it take up the entire right and left because right now it's leaving a little bit, [link] (http://prntscr.com/nt7rx9)

Comment: Instead of red update the color you want. Did you give any background color to inside element?